# How to pass value to date parameter in apex method from LWC JS?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, method-invocation

Please provide a proper way to call this method from LWC passing date parameter.

```
public with sharing class ApexClass {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true) 
    public Date string apexMethod(Date z) {
        return z;
    }
}
```

We got date type in aura component for this situation. Any such way in LWC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi i have used following code -

APEX Class -

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Date getDate(Date dt)
    {
        System.Debug('dt '+dt);
        return dt;

    }
```

and JS Code -

```
@wire(getDate,{dt:"2019-12-31"})
   date({data})
  { if(data){
      console.log("Data"+JSON.stringify(data));
  }
}
```

or

```
 @wire(getDate,{dt:new Date("2019-12-31")})
    date({data})
   { if(data){
       console.log("Data"+JSON.stringify(data));
   }

    }
```

And for My understanding, the date parameter accepts in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: I feel really great to know Date is accepting 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. Thank you so much

Comment: Could you give DateTime format as well?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is your apex method return value is wrong. Your method expect a string value to return but you are returning a date value.

The correct code is:-

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true) 
public static string apexMethod(Date z) {
    return String.valueOf(z);
}
```

Now, to call it from LWC, You can pass a date object value as parameter from JavaScript code:-

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import apexMethod from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.apexMethod';

export default class CurrencyInputField extends LightningElement {
     handleChange() {
        var d = new Date();
        apexMethod({ z: d })
            .then(result => {
                JSON.stringify('result ' + result);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                JSON.stringify('error ' + error);
            });
    }
}
```

Learn more about how to create a date instance in JavaScript here:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

and calling an apex method in LWC here:-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex

Comment: I tried yesterday, wire decorator was not calling the method. Now it's working wonder why. Anyway thanks for the answer and question fix. @sanket kumar